# Como juntar dois vetores em outro que não tenha valores repetidos?

Tags: c#, .net, array

Eu preciso fazer um programa que leia os valores de dois vetores `R` e `S`, e armazene os seus valores em um terceiro vetor chamado `V`. O detalhe é que não pode conter nenhum elemento repetido no vetor `V`.

Consegui fazer o programa mostrar o vetor `V` inteiro resultante da união de `R` e `S`, mas ainda não consegui bolar um jeito de não colocar elementos repetidos em `V`.

Segue o algoritmo que eu fiz:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Exercício6Testes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] R = new int[10];
            int[] S = new int[10];
            int[] V = new int[20];


            Console.WriteLine("Este programa lê dois vetores e mostra a união dos dois sem valores repetidos");
            Console.WriteLine("Digite os 10 valores do vetor R: ");
            Console.WriteLine("\n");



            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {

                Console.Write("Digite o valor de  R{0}: ", i + 1);   //LÊ O 1° VETOR
                R[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            }




            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Agora digite os valores do vetor S: ");

            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("Digite o valor de S{0}: ", j + 1); //LÊ O SEGUNDO VETOR
                S[j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


            }


            for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
            {
                V[k] = R[k];     //AQUI COLOCA TODOS OS VALORES DO VETOR R NAS
                                 //10 PRIMEIRAS POSIÇÕES DO VETOR V
            }



            int kw = 10;
            for (int L = 0; L < 10; L++)
            {
                V[kw] = S[L];  //AQUI COLOCA TODOS OS VALORES DO VETOR S NA
                kw++;          //SEGUNDA METADO DO VETOR V
            }



            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("União dos dois vetores: ");
            for(int mostra = 0; mostra < 20; mostra++)
            {
                Console.Write(V[mostra] + "\t");      //AQUI MOSTRA A UNIÃO DOS DOIS VETORES R e S DENTRO
                                                      //DO VETOR V.
                                                      //MOSTRA TUDO, ATÉ OS REPETIDOS!+......
            }




            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isto é para fins educacionais? É algum trabalho? Pergunto porque em C# existem formas muito mais simples de fazer o que pretende.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 2):

Tem várias maneiras de fazer isto e de forma mais fácil, mas seguindo o algoritmo pedido, fazendo de forma mais inteligente e simples, sem mudar muito muito seria isto:

```
using static System.Console;

namespace Exercício6Testes {
    public class Program {
        public static void Main() {
            int[] r = new int[10];
            int[] s = new int[10];
            int[] v = new int[20];
            WriteLine("Este programa lê dois vetores e mostra a união dos dois sem valores repetidos");
            WriteLine("Digite os 10 valores do vetor R:\n");
            var j = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                Write($"Digite o valor de  R{i + 1}: ");
                if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out r[i])) {
                    i--;
                    continue;
                }
                if (!EhRepetido(v, r[i], j)) v[j++] = r[i];
            }
            WriteLine("Agora digite os valores do vetor S: ");
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                Write($"Digite o valor de S{i + 1}: ");
                if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out s[i])) {
                    i--;
                    continue;
                }
                if (!EhRepetido(v, s[i], j)) v[j++] = s[i]; 
            }
            WriteLine("União dos dois vetores: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) Write($"{v[i]}\t");
        }
        public static bool EhRepetido(int[] vetor, int item, int posicao) {
            for (int i = 0; i < posicao; i++) if (vetor[i] == item) return true;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/4A8Cmg). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q9hPtj). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Array/UnionUnique.cs).

Modernizei o código. Não entendo porque as pessoas continuam programando em C# como era em 2002.

Fiz validação da digitação, do jeito que estava se a pessoa digitasse algo errado quebraria a aplicação, pode colocar ali uma mensagem de erro ou fazer alguma outra coisa para deixar mais claro que precisa digitar de novo. Decrementa o contador porque a contagem só pode ir pra frente com dado válido, e não executa mais nada abaixo.

Fiz uma rotina para identificar o repetido (não é a melhor performance, mas é como estava fazendo). Além de ser mais fácil por evitar uso de *flags*, evita repetição. Na verdade até a entrada de dados poderia evitar repetição. E já verifiquei direto na entrada de dados que é mais fácil e mais rápido.

No algoritmo postado fazia nada de filtro. Para filtrar repetido tem que varrer todo o *array* até a posição atual para ver se tem repetido, se tem encerra a busca, e só se nenhum for repetido é garantido de não ser repetido.

Por fim, só mando imprimir a quantidade de itens que tem validade no `V`. Como não usa `R` e `S` para nada, nem deveria ter criado essas variáveis.

Comment: Valeu jhow!+.......

Comment: @davidgomezsouza veja no [tour] a melhor maneira de dizer obrigado (aceitando a resposta) e faça isto em tudo o que já perguntou.